# How retain text of a drop down list and select data according to the value of selection?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Have an drop down list as follows:

```
 <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
 <!--
 function showSelected()
 {
var selObj = document.getElementById('city');
var cityTextObj = document.getElementById('cityText');

var selIndex = selObj.selectedIndex;
cityTextObj.value = selObj.options[selIndex].text;
 }
 //-->
 </script>

 <form method="get"><font class="text5">City</font>
    <select id="city" onchange="showSelected();this.form.submit();" style="width:350px">
    <option value="0">Please select</option>
        <option value="1">NewYork</option>
        <option value="2">Canada</option>
        <option value="3">Delhi</option>
        <option value="4">HongKong</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" id="cityText" name="cityText"/>

 </form>
```

and selecting database:

```
 <?php
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM general WHERE (day2sql >= now())";
 if(isset($_GET['cityText'])){
$city1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['cityText']);
$sql .= " AND (gcity = '$city1')";  
 }
```

This functions are working fine. The thing is if somebody selects HongKong, the form get submits and show the contents according to HongKong. But I am not able to retain HongKong text in the drop down list.Its going to default text "Please Select"

And there are 5 links like "ALL", "Today", "Tomorrow" etc.... if somebody selects HongKong. And clicks any of these 5 links Want get data according to HongKong ALL, HongKong TODAY, HongKong TOMORROW...... Like for all cities... Is this possible?

Comment: I think maybe it's from your form submission or your hidden field. Check them first.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <option value="1" <?= $_GET['cityText'] == "NewYork" ? 'selected' : '' ?> >NewYork</option>
    <option value="2" <?= $_GET['cityText'] == "Canada" ? 'selected' : '' ?> >Canada</option>
    <option value="3" <?= $_GET['cityText'] == "Delhi" ? 'selected' : '' ?> >Delhi</option>
    <option value="4" <?= $_GET['cityText'] == "HongKong" ? 'selected' : '' ?> >HongKong</option>
```

EDIT:

For ALL/TODAY/TOMORROW, it would be easier if you made them a menu or radio buttons in your form. Then when the form is submitted, the PHP can perform the appropriate query.

Comment: See the edited answer, I didn't notice that your Javascript is changing the values sent in the form submission. Why do you have `value="1"` in the first place if you're going to modify it? The default if you leave out the `value` attribute is to use the contents of the option.

Comment: OK...thanks... Its working....What about my second question? I am trying to do that last 3 days?!!!

Comment: Hi.... Its all working fine.... but whats the problem is... if somebody selects NewYork and selects some date and  given submit....the city text is retaining... again from there change the date column only...its not working

Comment: Since you've appended the date to the cityText value before submitting, your PHP will need to split them apart before using the values. It's not going to create `$_GET['show']` automatically, because the `&` gets encoded as part of the value.  Instead of appending to the value, I suggest you create another hidden form field and make `showSelected` fill that in.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make some modification to your code

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function showSelected(show)  //add parameter 'show' to keep value from user click
{
 var selObj = document.getElementById('city');
 var cityTextObj = document.getElementById('cityText');

 var selIndex = selObj.selectedIndex;
 cityTextObj.value = selObj.options[selIndex].text+"&show="+show;   //add variable 'show' to send
}
//-->
</script>

<form id="frm" method="get"><font class="text5">City</font>
  <select id="city" style="width:350px">
    <option value="0">Please select</option>
    <option value="1" <?php if($_GET["cityText"] == "NewYork") echo "selected"; ?> >NewYork</option>
    <option value="2" <?php if($_GET["cityText"] == "Canada") echo "selected"; ?> >Canada</option>
    <option value="3" <?php if($_GET["cityText"] == "Delhi") echo "selected"; ?> >Delhi</option>
    <option value="4" <?php if($_GET["cityText"] == "HongKong") echo "selected"; ?> >HongKong</option>
  </select>
</form>

<a href="#" onclick='showSelected("ALL");document.getElementById("frm").submit();'>ALL</a>
<a href="#" onclick='showSelected("TODAY");document.getElementById("frm").submit();'>TODAY</a>
<a href="#" onclick='showSelected("YESTERDAY");document.getElementById("frm").submit();'>YESTERDAY</a>
<a href="#" onclick='showSelected("TOMORROW");document.getElementById("frm").submit();'>TOMORROW</a>
```

and your php code:

```
<?php
 $show = $_GET["show"]; //using $show you can set the query to ALL,TODAY, or etc
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM general WHERE (day2sql >= now())";
 if(isset($_GET['cityText'])){
$city1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['cityText']);
$sql .= " AND (gcity = '$city1')";  
 }
```

Comment: if you are using the new version of xampp you need an extra configuration for using <?= tag,, so above I try to make ordinary php tag

Comment: thanks Bungdito...its working... How I select ALL TODAY Tomorrow....that I mentioned in my question?